# wordpress moving publish metabox

Tags: wordpress, layout, plugins, admin

I'm working on a plugin and I'm trying to:

1- move the publish metabox from side to the bottom of the page in the normal section.
2- force 1 column layout for the plugin custom post type edit page.
3- remove the screen options tab for the custom post type.

I'm using the next code block but it dont work:

```
function sds_do_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'sliding_panel', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'sliding_panel', 'normal', 'core' );
}
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'sds_do_meta_boxes');

function SDS_init() {  //The current user is already authenticated by this time             
        add_filter( 'screen_layout_columns', 'so_screen_layout_columns' );  
        add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'so_screen_layout_dashboard' );  
        add_filter( 'screen_options_show_screen', 'SDS_remove_screen_options_tab');                     
}

add_action( 'init', 'SDS_init' );

function so_screen_layout_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['dashboard'] = 1;
    return $columns;
}   
function so_screen_layout_dashboard() {
    return 1;
}
function SDS_remove_screen_options_tab() {
    return false;
}
```

So, the 'publish' metabox is removed but it is not re-added. Also, the 1 column layout  filters don't work. I need help:)

Answer (score -1):

Changing the `$priority` parameter from `core` to `high` and setting priority of `add_action` to `0` should do the trick. I would also suggest using the dynamic `add_meta_boxes_{$post_type}` hook:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_sliding_panel', 'sds_do_meta_boxes', 0, 1 );
function sds_do_meta_boxes( $post )
{
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'sliding_panel', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'sliding_panel', 'normal', 'high', null );
}
```

Comment: I tried that code on a local installation (with the `post` post type), and it moves the meta box right below the editor.

Comment: maybe give it a try with priority `999`?

Comment: I dont know what's wrong, the remove_meta_box function work but not the add_meta_box function even with the priority 999...the box stay on the side.

Comment: the filters to force 1 column layout dont work...nothing work in the code!!

Comment: it's because you already saving the the metabox order by saving the post type. In the clean installation of wordpress core, it will work.